AWS S3 transfer acceleration: Access Denied Error for IAM User with AdministratorAccess
Objective
To enable transfer acceleration for a S3 bucket in a management account in AWS Organization using an IAM user having AdministratorAccess.
Issue
Getting Access Denied error.
Some context

The account is a management account in an AWS organization.
The IAM user has AdministratorAccess attached to it.
Also attached the following policy to the IAM user.

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3AccelerateConfigAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutAccelerateConfiguration",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}


There is no bucket policy.

Bucket name is DNS-compliant, doesn't have any periods.

The issue persists even when using the root user.

When trying the same in another account within the organization (a non-management account) I'm able to create a S3 bucket and enable transfer acceleration. (same IAM user role-switching)



Any ideas ?
